# Take sample of first n distinct elements

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `mock` that has some string values:

```
CREATE TABLE mock (prop_a TEXT, prop_b TEXT);
```

With some random data

```
INSERT INTO mock (prop_a, prop_b) SELECT 'fake_a' || (i % 100), 'fake_b' || (i % 100) FROM generate_series(1, 100000) i
```

I want to obtain a summary of the values in the form of an array.

Something like:

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT prop_a), array_agg(DISTINCT prop_b) FROM mock
```

Suppose, that I only want to take 10 **distinct** values for each column (to show a sample to the user).

One could do

```
SELECT agg_a.array_agg, agg_b.array_agg
FROM
    (SELECT array_agg(prop_a)
     FROM
         (
             SELECT DISTINCT prop_a
             FROM mock
             LIMIT 10
         ) dist_a) agg_a,
    (SELECT array_agg(prop_b)
     FROM
         (
             SELECT DISTINCT prop_b
             FROM mock
             LIMIT 10
         ) dist_b) agg_b
```

But ideally there would be a syntax which would be something like:

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT prop_a LIMIT 10), array_agg(DISTINCT prop_b LIMIT 10) FROM mock
```

But I haven't found anything like it in the docs. Is there something like it? Or at least a least cumbersome way to do the query?

Comment: Do you want to take the first 10 elements and then remove their duplicates. Or do you want to take the first elements without any tied (first eliminating the duplicates and then taking the first 10)?

Comment: @S-Man I want to take samples on each column, each of the samples should have distinct in that column.

Answer (score 5):

You can take an appropriate array slice:

```
SELECT (array_agg(DISTINCT prop_a))[1:10],
       (array_agg(DISTINCT prop_b))[1:10]
FROM mock;
```

Comment: Oh, I see. What about this then?

Comment: Interesting solution! How is the performance? Will the 100000 elements be aggregated before the slicing?

Comment: That does indeed work. Do you know of performance implications? I would suspect that taking the array after would mean in fact doing the whole seq scan on the table to fetch all the distinct values.

Comment: Right. The best way to avoid that would be to write code that iterates through the table with a cursor and stops once it has found enough values. I thought you were looking for a syntactically simple solution, since you already have a working one.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe don't get me wrong, I like the solution that you propose. I think that it is elegant in the way that I'm looking for. But I'm also interested in the balance with performance (in case there is actually a penalty).

Comment: I just checked, changing the constants in the table, with 100k total elements and 10k distinct values (that is i % 10000). Doing distinct first means 116 ms and doing the slice later means 1s 350ms

Comment: Yes, that seems likely. I agree that it requires a sequential scan and will not be the fastest solution.